# Exim unable to sign DKIM keys for outgoing mail

Tags: linux, ssl, email, exim, dkim

I currently have an issue with exim, I am trying to make it so it will sign outgoing emails for specific domains with a key for DKIM (there are multiple domains that this server sends for and not all require DKIM)

The current config looks like this:

```
  dkim_canon = relaxed
  dkim_selector = 20150726
  dkim_domain = ${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}
  dkim_private_key = ${if exists {/etc/exim/dkim/${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}-private.pem}  {/etc/exim/dkim/${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}-private.pem}}
```

It seems to be working in the sense that when a domain that does not have keys for it is sent, nothing appears in the log, however when the one domain that I am testing with sends an email the following appears in panic.log (and also main.log)

```
2020-11-06 13:30:13 1kb1oj-00031L-AY Tainted filename '/etc/exim/dkim/example.com-private.pem'
2020-11-06 13:30:13 1kb1oj-00031L-AY unable to open file for reading: /etc/exim/dkim/example.com-private.pem
```

The directories the files are in all have 755 permissions and the dkim/ directory is owned by the user & group exim the files are also owned by exim and have 640 permissions (although during testing I had it at 777 just to make sure it was not a permission issue)

I am a bit lost as I have never implemented DKIM before, does anyone have any advice or am I missing something glaringly obvious?

It is running CentOS 7 as the underlying OS (not sure if that makes a difference)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's a new feature in Exim 4.94; anything coming from the email is considered potentially "tainted".

You can "untaint" `$h_from` by looking it up in a database or in a file.

For example, like this

```
DKIM_DOMAIN       = ${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}
DKIM_FILE         = ${lookup {dkim.DKIM_DOMAIN.key} dsearch,ret=full {/etc/exim4}}
dkim_private_key  = ${if exists{DKIM_FILE}{DKIM_FILE}{0}}
dkim_sign_headers = Date:Message-Id:From:To:Cc:Subject:Resent-Date:Resent-From:Resent-To:Resent-Cc
dkim_selector     = dkim
```

It relies on the [`dsearch` lookup](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-file_and_database_lookups.html):

> **dsearch**: The given file must be an absolute directory path; this is searched for an entry whose name is the key by calling the *lstat()* function. The key may not contain any forward slash characters. If *lstat()* succeeds then so does the lookup. The result is regarded as untainted.

The expression `${lookup {dkim.DKIM_DOMAIN.key} dsearch,ret=full {/etc/exim4}}` will succeed when a file `/etc/exim4/dkim.DKIM_DOMAIN.key` is found.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that you create the path to the private key from the mail itself. This makes the path based on untrusted user input, hence the *Tainted filename ...* problem.

To fix this you probably need to have several fixed path  and decide which of these path  to use based on mail, instead of creating the path dynamically based on the mail.